# navigator.webkitGetUserMedia stream improperly updating [electron's DesktopCapturer]

Tags: html5-video, video-capture, chromium, electron, getusermedia

I am using the [example electron provides](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/desktop-capturer.md) for DesktopCapturer to grab the an application's stream and attach it to a `<video>`

The stream I am capturing is the game Dota 2. Users have been experiencing one of two things with this:

1. The video reflects Dota as you interact with it, as expected.
2. The video shows a frozen image of the interface from when it first starts up, however you can see the mouse cursor moving around ([you can see the interface with the cursor here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwlSL.jpg))

We have narrowed it down to the Dota 2 application given that capturing the full screen that Dota 2 is on works just fine.

What is it that could be causing `navigator.webkitGetUserMedia` stream to not receive the proper image of the application? I assume the reason why the cursor updates is because it's treated separately internally by Dota 2.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in Chrome? If so you should probably open an issue with the Chromium folks.

Comment: Good call, asking them to check. Will report back.

Comment: Confirmed. Will report with the Chromium guys: https://gyazo.com/89ff8643f8474d153181a96c9adfc100